# Rails: Pass Parameters to New Controller during 'redirect_to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I'm using Ryan Bates' Rails Cast on Wicked Wizard Forms to create a multi-step form. I don't have a     `current_user` method defined (not using an authentication gem) - so, I'm trying to pass the `user.id` parameter during the `redirect_to` - unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

My user controller `create` method

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to controller: 'user_steps', id: 'user.id' }
        #format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }#
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The `user_steps` controller that to which I am redirecting:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps :gender, :items, :brands, :final

    def show
        render_wizard
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass it through as a param, ideally, which the `redirect_to` method will do for you if you use a proper route path.

Example:

```
redirect_to(user_steps_path(@user))
```

In your case, if you don't have a named route, you might do this:

```
redirect_to(controller: 'user_steps', id: @user.to_param)
```

In URLs it's advisable to use the `to_param` method. `id` is used for database queries.

What you're passing in is literally `'user.id'` as a parameter. It will not be evaluated.

Comment: Gotcha - I tried both `(user_steps_path(@user))` and `id: @user.to_param` and for some reason, the db isn't updated with the attribute value on the subsequent page. Perhaps it's an issue with my routes - I'm getting "No route matches [POST] "/user_steps/gender" (where gender is a view under the `user_steps` controller). Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You should check `log/development.log` to see if the user record is successfully saved or not. It should be based on your `if` there.